# Acessar os dados do usuário via Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Tenho o modelo de usuário que extendi do padrão do Django

```
class TradingUser(User):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='images/none.jpg')
```

Só que quando tento acessar essa imagem do avatar via template

```
<img src=" {{ user.avatar }}">
```

Ele retorna vazio, acredito que o usuário do Django está como "User" e não como "TradingUser". Mas ao mudar no settings.py aconteceram vários erros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nessa situação, você precisa usar o TrandingUser no template também. Exemplo:

```
<img src="{{request.user.tradinguser.avatar.url}}">
```

Comment: Caraca, que simples, como não pensei nisso antes. Muito obrigado.